# Set the permissions of all files copied in a folder the same

Tags: linux, permissions, cloud, usergroups

I would like to create a folder (in Linux) that can be used as cloud-like storage location, where all files **copied** there automatically will have g+rw permissions (without the need of chmod'ing), such that they are readable and writable by people beloning to that specific group.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command *setfacl*, e.g.:

```
setfacl -d -m g::rwx test/
```

It sets the rwx permissions to every new file in test/ folder.

```
$ touch test/test
$ ls -la test/
total 48
drwxr-xr-x  2 manu manu  4096 Jan 28 08:39 .
drwxrwxrwt 20 root root 40960 Jan 28 08:39 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 manu manu     0 Jan 28 08:39 test
$ setfacl -d -m g::rwx test/
$ ls -la test/
total 48
drwxr-xr-x+  2 manu manu  4096 Jan 28 08:39 .
drwxrwxrwt  20 root root 40960 Jan 28 08:39 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 manu manu     0 Jan 28 08:39 test
$ touch test/test2
$ ls -la test/
total 48
drwxr-xr-x+  2 manu manu  4096 Jan 28 08:40 .
drwxrwxrwt  20 root root 40960 Jan 28 08:39 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 manu manu     0 Jan 28 08:39 test
-rw-rw-r--   1 manu manu     0 Jan 28 08:40 test2
```

Comment: Thanks. I have already tried that and it works when creating new files and new directories but it does not work when copying files.

Comment: It might depend on how you copy the files.  Some options to the `cp` command attempt to preserve attributes.